# Transparent JList smears when selecting elements or scrolling

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, transparency, jlist

I have a transparent JList and JScrollPanel on top of a gradient JPanel the code for each of those looks like this:

```
JPanel midPanel = new JPanel() {
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Paint p = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(233, 220, 0, 0),
             getWidth(), getHeight(), new Color(239, 129, 91, 255), true);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2d.setPaint(p);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    };
```

List code

```
    ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {elements...}));
    
    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
    model.addAll(songs);

    JList<String> songList = new JList<String>(model);

    songList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    songList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    songList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
    songList.setOpaque(false);
    songList.setCellRenderer(new TransparentListCellRenderer());

    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(songList);
    scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));
    scroller.setOpaque(false);
    scroller.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    scroller.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

    midPanel.add(scroller);
```

Before anything is touched it looks like this:
[image: working image]

And after stuff gets selected or scrolling the elements of the list all smear and create this mess: [image: Smeared Image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? if I had to guess what was wrong it would be an issue with the gradient because the paintComponet() method is overridden so it's not getting redrawn properly but if that is the case I do not know how to fix it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Swing doesn't support transparent color directly. Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for a solution.

Comment: @camickr They do support transparency with the setOpaque() method and a custom cell renderer that renders the list items transparently. Regardless this site doesn't seem to have the solution to my problem because I already have a transparent list it's just smearing because it's not being redrawn properly.

Comment: The setOpaque(...) method only supports full transparency at the component level. You are attempting to do transparent painting by using alpha values for your Color objects of your GradientPaint, which is NOT supported directly. The link you have been given explains why it doesn't work and shows how to implement transparency when using alpha values in your Color objects.

Comment: @camickr No way, alright I was very skeptical that it would work but it worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to wrap the panel in a Container that is a sort of transparent.

```java
public class AlphaContainer extends JComponent {
    private JComponent component;

    public AlphaContainer(JComponent component) {
        this.component = component;
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        setOpaque( false );
        component.setOpaque( false );
        add( component );
    }

    /**
     *  Paint the background using the background Color of the
     *  contained component
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor( component.getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```